# Android Studio is having a strange "cascading display" glitch?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm having some weird problems running Android Studio as of late. Operationally, it's fine, but the display keeps "cascading" randomly and without provocation. Here's [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zibSr.png) of what I'm talking about. I reinstalled Studio from scratch and it still occurs. I don't think it's my rig, as I have zero problems running anything else, but who knows.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

Add

sun.java2d.d3d=false

Works for me. Something with hardware acceleration went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this issue myself. Reported the issue on the AOSP Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193976&thanks=193976&ts=1447362824

Comment: I updated JDK to JDK 8u65 and haven't had the issue since. Worth a try if you already haven't.

Comment: "Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

Add

sun.java2d.d3d=false

Works for me. Something with hardware acceleration went wrong." Did not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows assuming you're running one it might have to do with external OSD programs such as Msi's Afterburner/RivaTunerStatisticsServer. Exiting this application whenever I get this issue on a Windows machine seems to resolve it. It doesn't however explain why I sometimes get the issue on a computer running OSX Yosemite and above. So if you get the issue and you use a similar program try terminating it and see if it helps.