# Android Studio 1.4.1 visual glitch

Tags: android-studio

When I was using the Android Studio (1.4.1), after a while I ran into some visual glitches. I then fixed these by moving the window to my secondary monitor. This then happened again, after about 5 minutes.

[image: Glitch]

I was wondering if this was documented, and if there is a known way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Studio is having a strange "cascading display" glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531985/android-studio-is-having-a-strange-cascading-display-glitch)

Try this:

Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

Add

sun.java2d.d3d=false

Comment: Or Android Studio main menu => `Help` => `Edit Custom Properties ...`. And add `sun.java2d.d3d` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Java and DirectX are colliding on 2D issues.

You will have the same problem with many java apps on that graphic card.
It seems that the DirectX and Java have a collision on specific system settings.

To solve this:

In windows:

1. open Environment Variables
2. add a new variable
3. name it `_JAVA_OPTIONS`
4. add the following value `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`