# Android Studio graphic bug with the IDE - doubled view

Tags: android, android-studio, interface, editor, graphic

I'm facing this graphic bug:

[image]
[image]

It's always at the bottom right of the cursor. Not the mouse. Whenever the cursor is not moving on the editor, the graphic bug pops up like intellisense, and it doubles the android studio like in the picture.

I'm using AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series graphics card. And using AMD Catalyst suite version 15.201.

Comment: Update [1] : I re-install it. Didn't work. The problem still there.

Comment: Update [2] : I try using "Latest Android Studio Canary Build: 2.0 Preview 4", still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "sun.java2d.d3d=false" to "Android Studio\bin\idea.properties". This worked for me.

See here: [Android Studio is having a strange "cascading display" glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531985/android-studio-is-having-a-strange-cascading-display-glitch)

[edit: spelling]

Comment: Yup. That fix it. Thank you. I like to give you up vote, but don't have enough rep yet. Sorry.

Comment: Yup. Didn't know that was a thing. Thanks for reminding me.